# setting a new screen with libgdx crashes my game?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, scene2d

So i cant seem to figured out for the life of me why setting a new screen crashes my game, the log message i get seems pretty straight forward but i just cant find the root of it so i was hoping someone could help me out here.. Here is the log message

```
java(1240,0x1e59cb000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8cf4ad2208: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Here is the code that calls the setScreen method, I don't see where i'm modifying a freed object Hopefully someone can enlighten me on this subject

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
//..
public void updateWorld(float deltaTime){

        switch (gameState) {
            case START:
                //..
                break;

            case RUNNING:
                //..
                break;

            case GAMEOVER:
                System.out.println("called");
                //..
                fishy.setGRAVITY(-20);
                fishy.update(deltaTime);

                if (gos == null) gos = new GameOverState(game);
                gos.compareScore(curr_ig_score);
                backgroundMusic.pause();
                if (!gameOver.isPlaying()) gameOver.play();
                fishy.setMOVEMENT_X(0);

                updateGOSButtons();
                break;
            case PAUSED:
                //...
                break;
        }

        //..
    }

public void updateGOSButtons() {
            if (gos.isGoButtonClicked()) {
                gameOver.stop();
                backgroundMusic.play();
                dispose();
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            }

            if (gos.isHomeButtonClicked()) {
                gameOver.stop();
                backgroundMusic.play();
                dispose();
                game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
            }

            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gos.getStage());
    }
```

}

Comment: what is your **dispose()** method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From another thread:

> What's happening is one of the following:
>
> 1) you are freeing an object twice,
>
> 2) you are freeing a pointer that was never allocated
>
> 3)you are writing through an invalid pointer which previously pointed to
>   an object which was already freed

The best way is to put a breakpoint in the: `malloc_error_break` methods and see what's happening. Without more info it's impossible for us to help!

Comment: it turns out that I was not disposing of a stage running in another thread, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem recently that was caused when I changed screens in the middle of the render cycle. What was happening was the current screen would be hid and disposed of, then it would try to render it still using the stage and other objects that had already been disposed of. I had to move the set screen method to the end of the render call and problem solved.